# Facebook Api Call Ready

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am having a synchronisation issue in Javascript. Code below. When I make the call to get mutual friends, although my function is still filling the array through the API callback, the printing of `"Quite a bunch: 0"` happens **before**  the printing of the - `console.log(friendID +" -> " + mutualfriends.data.length);`

I know this must be a callback / asynch issue but I have no idea how to deal with it. I'm filling the array for a reason - need it to be filled for the next part.

code:

```
function getMutualFriends(friendID)
{
  //console.log(response.data[i].id);
  try{

           FB.api('/me/mutualfriends/'+friendID, function(mutualfriends) {
             //console.log(mutualfriends);
             //console.log(mutualfriends.data.length);

             console.log(friendID +" -> " + mutualfriends.data.length);
             mutualFriendsList.push([friendID,mutualfriends.data.length]);
           });
    }
  catch(err){
    console.log('error caught: ' +err);
  }

}

function getFriendsList()
{
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){   
    FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {

         for(i=0; i<response.data.length;i++)
         {
           var friendID = response.data[i].id;
           console.log(friendID);
           friendsList.push(friendID);
         }

         console.log('Interesting, we gathered: '+friendsList.length+' friends,');

         console.log('lets check mutual friends now');

        for(j=0; j<friendsList.length;j++)
        {
          getMutualFriends(friendsList[j]);
        }

        console.log('Quite a bunch: ' + mutualFriendsList.length);

        });//friends
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll probably want to turn your "post-condition" code into a callback.

So where you now have:

```
for(j=0; j<friendsList.length;j++)
{
  getMutualFriends(friendsList[j]);
}

console.log('Quite a bunch: ' + mutualFriendsList.length);
```

You'll want something like:

```
for(j=0; j<friendsList.length;j++)
{
  getMutualFriends(friendsList[j], function(mutualFriendsList) {
    console.log('Quite a bunch: ' + mutualFriendsList.length);
  });
}
```

When you set it up like this, your `getMutualFriends` function can call the callback once it got the result:

```
function getMutualFriends(friendID, callback)
{
   FB.api('/me/mutualfriends/'+friendID, function(mutualfriends) {
     mutualFriendsList.push([friendID,mutualfriends.data.length]);
     callback(mutualFriendsList);
   });
}
```

This will do the callback once for every call to `getMutualFriends`. If you want the callback to only trigger once for **all** friends, you'll need to expand the concept a bit further.

**Update**:

You could combine the above "per friend" callback with @RGDev's condition to detect the last friend:

```
for(j=0; j<friendsList.length;j++)
{
  getMutualFriends(friendsList[j], function(mutualFriendsList) {
    if (mutualFriendsList.length == friendsList.length) {
      console.log('Quite a bunch: ' + mutualFriendsList.length);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

getMutualFriends is doing an async call on his own (by calling FB.api) so you cannot print the mutualFriendsList until it's done (actually, you are doing may calls to getMutualFiends so your mutualFriendsList won't be accurate until all of them finished their async processing).

Can't you rely on that collection to be async? I don't know what you are doing with that, but maybe (if you are drawing it in the screen by example) you can issue a redraw of that component every time the callback of FB.api('/me/mutualfriends/'+friendID, ...) is done.

I had a similar issue to you in the past, I solved it by using a backbone.js' collection instead of a simple javascript array. Then I bound a listener to the add event of the collection and print the qty of friends every time an object was added to it.

Good luck,

Answer (score 0):

You could use a while loop to wait until the mutualFriendsList.length is equal to friendsList.length. which would mean that all of the ajax functions return functions had been fulfilled.

It would look something like:

```
while(mutualFriendsList.length != friendsList.length)
{
console.log("Still Waiting");

 }
console.log('done')
// do your data processing
```

A little inelegant, but it should work

Comment: That will create a tight loop, which is a bad idea in asynchronous callbacks. Your CPU could be spinning in that loop for seconds, depending on the number of friends and the turn-around time on the `FB.api` calls.

Comment: yeah, your solution is much better, I've never used the callback function before. I'll keep it in mind for future use.